# Vector of objects belonging to a trait

Tags: polymorphism, rust

Consider the following code:

```rust
trait Animal {
    fn make_sound(&self) -> String;
}

struct Cat;
impl Animal for Cat {
    fn make_sound(&self) -> String {
        "meow".to_string()
    }
}

struct Dog;
impl Animal for Dog {
    fn make_sound(&self) -> String {
        "woof".to_string()
    }
}

fn main () {
    let dog: Dog = Dog;
    let cat: Cat = Cat;
    let v: Vec<Animal> = Vec::new();
    v.push(cat);
    v.push(dog);
    for animal in v.iter() {
        println!("{}", animal.make_sound());
    }
}
```

The compiler tells me that `v` is a vector of `Animal` when I try to push `cat` (type mismatch)

So, how can I make a vector of objects belonging to a trait and calls the corresponding trait method on each element?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The existing answers explain the problem with `Vec<Animal>` well, but they use older syntax, which is not valid anymore.

In short, the vector needs to contain [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) and its type should be (something like) `Vec<Box<dyn Animal>>`.

In modern Rust, the [`dyn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.dyn.html) keyword is used to specify a trait object. But we cannot use just `Vec<dyn Animal>`, because `dyn Animal` is not *sized* (`Cat` and `Dog` could pottentially have fields of different size). Vectors can only contain elements of a fixed size. So that's why in the vector we should rather store some sort of *pointers* to the actual structs. The [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) struct is one such option, a kind of a [smart pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html) that has a fixed size in itself.

Let's test this (on a 64-bit machine):

```
use std::mem::size_of;
println!("size Cat = {}", size_of::<Cat>());  // 0 bytes (the Cat struct has no fields)
println!("size Dog = {}", size_of::<Dog>());  // 0 bytes (the Dog struct has no fields)
println!("size BoxCat = {}", size_of::<Box<Cat>>());  // 8 bytes (1 usize pntr)
println!("size BoxDyn = {}", size_of::<Box<dyn Animal>>());  // 16 bytes (2 usize pointers)
println!("{}", size_of::<dyn Animal>());  // Error: doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

Note that if `Cat` had fields, `size_of::<Cat>()` would have been more than `0`, but `size_of::<Box<Cat>>()` and `size_of::<Box<dyn Animal>>()` wouldn't change at all.

Also note that `Box<dyn Animal>` actually contains 2 pointers:

- one that points to the actual struct instance data;
- one for the [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) (that's because of `dyn`; it's needed for [dynamic dispatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)).

Now to your example. To make it work, you just need to replace these three lines:

```
let v: Vec<Animal> = Vec::new();
v.push(cat);
v.push(dog);
```

with these:

```
let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn Animal>> = Vec::new();
v.push(Box::new(cat));
v.push(Box::new(dog));
```

Comment: Very clear answer, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 100):

`Vec<Animal>` is not legal, but the compiler can't tell you that because the type mismatch somehow hides it. If we remove the calls to `push`, the compiler gives us the following error:

```
<anon>:22:9: 22:40 error: instantiating a type parameter with an incompatible type `Animal`, which does not fulfill `Sized` [E0144]
<anon>:22     let mut v: Vec<Animal> = Vec::new();
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The reason why that's not legal is that a `Vec<T>` stores many `T` objects consecutively in memory. However, `Animal` is a trait, and traits have no size (a `Cat` and a `Dog` are not guaranteed to have the same size).

To solve this problem, we need to store something that has a size in the `Vec`. The most straightforward solution is to wrap the values in a [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html), i.e. `Vec<Box<Animal>>`. `Box<T>` has a fixed size (a "fat pointer" if `T` is a trait, a simple pointer otherwise).

Here's a working `main`:

```
fn main() {
    let dog: Dog = Dog;
    let cat: Cat = Cat;
    let mut v: Vec<Box<Animal>> = Vec::new();
    v.push(Box::new(cat));
    v.push(Box::new(dog));
    for animal in v.iter() {
        println!("{}", animal.make_sound());
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be using trait objects, i.e. dynamic dispatch. However, [the Rust Programming Language book on this topic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/trait-objects.html) says "one can always have a thin statically-dispatched wrapper function that does a dynamic dispatch, but not vice versa, meaning static calls are more flexible." Is there actually a way to not use trait objects and only perform static dispatch in this case? I also encountered the use case where I want to have a vector storing potentially different types of structs implementing the same trait.

Comment: @JIXiang If you know in advance what concrete types you'll be putting in the `Vec`, you can use an `enum` instead (and then the trait might become redundant). Otherwise, no, you can't avoid dynamic dispatch. Keep in mind that dynamic dispatch is not inherently evil; there are situations where it's OK to use it!

Comment: The preferred way to write this is now `Box<dyn Animal>`.

Comment: @Boiethios Now it's required.

Comment: Yes, can **confirm** that the syntax is now expected as `Box<dyn Animal>`.

Answer (score 25):

You may use a reference trait object `&Animal` to borrow the elements and store these trait objects in a `Vec`. You can then enumerate it and use the trait's interface.

Altering the `Vec`'s generic type by adding a `&` in front of the trait will work:

```
fn main() {
    let dog: Dog = Dog;
    let cat: Cat = Cat;
    let mut v: Vec<&Animal> = Vec::new();
    //             ~~~~~~~
    v.push(&dog);
    v.push(&cat);
    for animal in v.iter() {
        println!("{}", animal.make_sound());
    }
    // Ownership is still bound to the original variable.
    println!("{}", cat.make_sound());
}
```

This is great if you may want the original variable to keep ownership and reuse it later.

Keep in mind with the scenario above, you can't transfer ownership of `dog` or `cat` because the `Vec` has borrowed these concrete instances at the same scope.

Introducing a new scope can help handle that particular situation:

```
fn main() {
    let dog: Dog = Dog;
    let cat: Cat = Cat;
    {
        let mut v: Vec<&Animal> = Vec::new();
        v.push(&dog);
        v.push(&cat);
        for animal in v.iter() {
            println!("{}", animal.make_sound());
        }
    }
    let pete_dog: Dog = dog;
    println!("{}", pete_dog.make_sound());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the missing clue for me. In newer Rust version, I think there needs to be inserted a `dyn`, like this `Vec<&dyn Animal>`.