# Object to trait conversion

Tags: rust, traits

Assuming the following Rust code:

```
trait  MyTrait {...}
struct MyStruct;
impl   MyTrait for MyStruct {...}
impl   MyStruct {
     pub fn new() -> MyStruct { MyStruct{...} }
}
```

I'm able to write:

```
let foo: MyStruct = MyStruct::new();
```

However I can't

```
let bar: MyTrait  = MyStruct::new();
```

Other interface-oriented programming languages can do that. Am I missing something? How can I pass various objects to a method that accepts only `MyTrait`? Do I need to use "templates" such as `my_method<T: MyTrait>(param: T) {...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define `bar` as a `MyTrait` object. (This is even the wrong thinking, because rust doesn't really have inheritance. Think of traits as more like interfaces in Java. In this case, it seems like you're treating `MyTrait` as a superclass of `MyStruct`)

You can do this

```
let bar = MyStruct::new();
```

and then just pass it in function defined like this:

```
fn my_method<T: MyTrait>(param: T) {...}

my_method(bar)
```

This works because Rust statically checks that `bar`, which is of type `MyStruct`, implements the trait `MyTrait`.

Side note: If you want to create a vector of trait objects, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818082/vector-of-objects-belonging-to-a-trait) question.

Comment: I think of traits as interfaces in Java, therefore I expect `MyInterface i = new MyClass();` be working. Anyway, thanks for help, I'll do it as you proposed.

Comment: @petrbel: that would be equivalent to `let bar: Box<MyTrait> = Box::new(MyStruct::new());`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a trait may be implmented by many types and therefor the size of `bar` is unknown. However a reference's size would be know, so the following works.

```
trait MyTrait {}
struct MyStruct;
impl MyTrait for MyStruct {}
impl MyStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyStruct
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo: MyStruct = MyStruct::new();
    let bar: &MyTrait = &MyStruct::new();
}
```

Notice that `bar` isn't a `MyTrait`, it's a `&MyTrait`, this is called a [trait object](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/trait-objects.html).