# Define vector with tuple of any type

Tags: vector, types, rust

I'm trying to define a custom structure with a field that can be a `std::vec::Vec` with **any** type of element:

```
use std::vec::Vec;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct BertDictionary {
    data: Vec<(Any, Any)>  // not work also with Vec<(_, _)>
}
```

When compiling, this generates a [E0308 error](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0308) which means the compiler is unable to infer the concrete type. Is is possible to define such a structure?

As an example, I'm going to use this vector when each element may be represented like `(name, "user"), (id, 1)` and so on.

Comment: Are you aware of `AnyMap`? And be aware that getting the value out of `Any` requires knowing its concrete type.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sure, I know about that Any require implementing trait for your types, but doesn't know something about AnyMap. Maybe it's a good fit, however I wonder if can I write this constructions which described in this topic

Comment: [`AnyMap`](https://github.com/chris-morgan/anymap) is written by Chris Morgan and [`rust-typemap`](https://github.com/reem/rust-typemap) is written by Jonathan Reem, if you are interested in investigating them.

Comment: Thanks you for the useful answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vector of objects belonging to a trait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818082/vector-of-objects-belonging-to-a-trait)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any` is a trait, not a concrete type, so you need to add a generic type parameter to the struct.

```
struct BertDirectory<T: Any> {
    data: Vec<T>
}
```

You might also want to ensure that `T` is also something that implements `Debug` and `PartialEq`. This isn't required to compile, but would be if you want to ensure that `BertDirectory` always implements those traits. Otherwise, it will only implement `Debug` when `T` does so.

```
struct BertDirectory<T: Any + Debug + PartialEq> {
    data: Vec<T>
}
```

Even given both of those things I don't know that this will give you what you really want because `data` will still be constrained to hold a *single type*. `T` can only ever represent a single type per instance of the struct.

If you need `data` to store values of different types, you might instead want to look into using [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html) instead, which is Rust's way of using vTables:

```
pub trait MyTrait: Debug {
    // you can still use Any by doing MyTrait: Any + Debug
    // Note that you won't be able to derive PartialEq for your trait 
    // because PartialEq can't be made into a TraitObject

    // can also define whatever methods you would want on your data, which
    // might be preferable to using Any, if possible
}

pub struct BertDirectory<T: MyTrait>{
    data: Vec<(Box<MyTrait>, Box<MyTrait>)>
}
```

That way the concrete type of `T` would not need to be known at compile time. Each element in `data` could be of a different concrete type and the correct methods would be called automatically. You would not be able to derive `PartialEq`, though, so you'd just have to implement that yourself.