# Rust compiler does not see structure as Sized

Tags: rust

I am trying to define a trait as follows:

```
pub struct Parameter<A: Parameterisable>(&'static str, Box<A>);

pub trait Parameterisable {
    // Some functions
}

impl Parameterisable for i32 {}
impl Parameterisable for f64 {}

pub struct ParameterCollection(Vec<Parameter<Parameterisable>>);
```

That is, the parameter collection is a mixture of parameters of different types. However compiling gives the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Parameterisable + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:32
   |
10 | pub struct ParameterCollection(Vec<Parameter<Parameterisable>>);
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ trait `Parameterisable + 'static: std::marker::Sized` not satisfied
   |
   = note: `Parameterisable + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   = note: required by `Parameter`
```

I am aware from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818082/vector-of-objects-belonging-to-a-trait) that `Vec` must be `Sized`, but it seems that `Parameter` should be sized (because of the `Box`) so how do I convince the Rust compiler that `Parameter` is a `Sized` type?

Comment: `A: Parameterisable + ?Sized`?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work... I tried:
`pub struct Parameter<A: Parameterisable>(&'static str,Box<A>) where A: Sized`
But that did not work

Comment: You should update your version of Rust to get more readable error messages.

Comment: @Dogbert: Shouldn't `Box` accepts Unsized parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type parameters in Rust have an [implicit `Sized` bound](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/the-sized-trait/) unless otherwise specified (by adding a `?Sized` bound).

So the `Parameter` struct declaration is effectively:

```
pub struct Parameter<A: Parameterisable+Sized>(&'static str, Box<A>);
```

Note that `Parameter<T>` is always itself sized, since `&'static str` and `Box<A>` are always sized; the bound just says that `T` must also be sized.

The error message backs this up; it's saying that `Parameterisable` is not `Sized`, not that `Parameter<Parametrerisable>` is not `Sized`.

So the correct change is to add the `?Sized` bound:

```
pub struct Parameter<A: Parameterisable+?Sized>(&'static str, Box<A>);
```