# Method call resolution for `Box`ed type

Tags: rust

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=be2fd4d44475b76cebe2a776b8ac12bd&version=stable):

```
trait FnBox {
    fn call_box(self: Box<Self>);
}

impl<F: FnOnce()> FnBox for F {
    fn call_box(self: Box<F>) {
        (*self)()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let job: Box<FnOnce()> = Box::new(|| {});
    // versions that compile
    // let job = Box::new(|| {});
    // let job: Box<FnBox> = Box::new(|| {});
    job.call_box();
}
```

`job.call_box();` doesn't compile:

> ```
> error[E0599]: no method named `call_box` found for type `std::boxed::Box<std::ops::FnOnce()>` in the current scope
>   --> src/main.rs:16:9
>    |
> 16 |     job.call_box();
>    |         ^^^^^^^^
>    |
>    = note: job is a function, perhaps you wish to call it
>    = note: the method `call_box` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
>            `std::ops::FnOnce() : FnBox`
>    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
>    = note: the following trait defines an item `call_box`, perhaps you need to implement it:
>            candidate #1: `FnBox`
> ```

Why doesn't the compiler see the conversion to `FnBox` here?

I suppose when I use `let job = Box::new(|| {});` that results in a `Box<closure>` type. The compiler manages to resolve `job.call_box()`, which is `Box<closure>` -> `Box<FnOnce()>` -> `Box<FnBox>` (because `FnBox` is implemented for `FnOnce()`, not for `closure`). Why doesn't just `Box<FnOnce()>` -> `Box<FnBox>` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Author's note:* Since Rust 1.35, an adapter trait like `FnBox` is not required to call boxed `FnOnce` closures; read to the end to see why.

`FnBox` *isn't* implemented for `FnOnce()`.

`FnOnce()` has two meanings: as a trait, and as a type. In `Box<FnOnce()>`, it's a (dynamic, unsized) type. [Since Rust 1.27, the type can be written more explicitly as `dyn FnOnce()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/3650362) For the rest of this answer I will use `dyn` in order to make clear when I'm talking about the trait and when about the dynamic type.

The `impl` you wrote doesn't implement `FnBox` for the type `dyn FnOnce()`, because [generic parameters have an implicit `Sized` bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846232/rust-compiler-does-not-see-structure-as-sized/40847616#40847616). If we follow the advice of that question's answer and add `+ ?Sized` to `F`, the compiler does give a slightly more helpful error message:

```
impl<F: FnOnce() + ?Sized> FnBox for F {
    fn call_box(self: Box<F>) {
        (*self)()
    }
}
```

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type F: the size of F cannot be statically determined
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         (*self)()
  |         ^^^^^^^
```

Which does explicitly call out the place where `Sized`ness is required.

In versions of Rust before 1.35, there was no way to fix this error; trait objects of `FnOnce()` were just useless. However, today `Box<dyn FnOnce()>` implements `FnOnce()`, so you can call it like a normal closure, without using `*`:

```
impl<F: FnOnce() + ?Sized> FnBox for F {
    fn call_box(self: Box<F>) {
        self()
    }
}
```

#### See also

- [What does "Box<Fn() + Send + 'static>" mean in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017290/what-does-boxfn-send-static-mean-in-rust)
- [Rust Trait object conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604107/rust-trait-object-conversion) (why you can't go from one trait object type to another)

Comment: You can [make this work with `#![feature(unsized_locals)]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=561c4dca058db42dc4ae32bc58cb8159).