# Vector of generic trait objects

Tags: generics, types, enums, rust, polymorphism

*(This is my second try to track down my exact problem. See the edit history)*

I have a simple generic Trait and two different implementations:

```
pub trait MyTrait<T=Self> where T: MyTrait {
}

struct Impl1;
impl MyTrait for Impl1 {
}

struct Impl2;
impl MyTrait for Impl2 {
}
```

I now want a vector that contains elements of both implementations. As I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25819164/6094756), I do:

```
fn foo() {
    let mut traits: Vec<Box<MyTrait>> = Vec::new();
    traits.push(Box::new(Impl1{}));
    traits.push(Box::new(Impl2{}));
}
```

But the compiler doesn't agree:

```
error[E0393]: the type parameter `T` must be explicitly specified
  --> src/main.rs:25
   |
25 |     let mut traits: Vec<Box<MyTrait>> = Vec::new();
   |                             ^^^^^^^ missing reference to `T`
   |
   = note: because of the default `Self` reference, type parameters must be specified on object types
```

On the one hand, that makes sense. On the other hand, what should I put for `T`? I want this to be generic, so I can't simply put there `Impl1` or `Impl2`. I could do `Vec<Box<MyTrait<MyTrait>>>`, but this will only move the error, not resolve it.

---

**Edit**

The code above is the minimal failing one, here's a slightly less minimal implementation:

```
enum MyEnum<T: MyTrait> {
    A(T),
    B
}

pub trait MyTrait<T=Self> where T: MyTrait {
    fn do_stuff(self) -> MyEnum<T>;
}

struct Impl1;
impl MyTrait for Impl1 {
    fn do_stuff(self) -> MyEnum<Impl1> {
        MyEnum::A(self)
    }
}

struct Impl2;
impl MyTrait for Impl2 {
    fn do_stuff(self) -> MyEnum<Impl2> {
        MyEnum::B
    }
}
```

Each `MyTrait` object consumes itself and can either result in a `MyEnum::A` containing another `MyTrait` object or a `MyEnum::B`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the generic parameter in `MyTrait<T=Self>`? Where are you using T in the trait?

Comment: The edit suggests you have a problem in mind, but you are not explaining that, just showing specific, failing, attempt to solve it. Try to describe the higher level problem so we can try to guide you to whatever is preferred solution for that. `dyn Trait` and `enum`s have their own advantages and disadvantages and which you should use depends on the wider requirements you have.

Comment: Ad edit: but implementation *of what?* Mixing static (generics) and dynamic (trait objects, enums) polymorphism does not work well. You need to come up with another representation, and nobody can help you if they don't know representation of what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic things—does not matter whether traits, types or functions—are not code that can be addressed, but merely templates for code to be generated when you substitute them. So they are not “object-safe”, i.e. you can't use them for types of dynamic references and smart pointers. You can only use their specific instances.

`MyTrait` is generic, so you can't have `&dyn MyTrait` or `Box<dyn MyTrait>`. You can only have `&dyn MyTrait<Impl1>` or `Box<dyn MyTrait<Impl1>>`.

You do have a default value for the parameter, but `Self` is special, because `Self` is the type that implements the trait, and as such only makes sense in the `impl` definition. But not in the free function where you are trying to declare `Vec<Box<MyTrait>>`. That's why it can't be compiled.

Also due to how special `Self` is, `impl MyTrait for Impl1` gets desugared to `impl MyTrait<Impl1> for Impl1` and `impl MyTrait for Impl2` gets desugared to `impl MyTrait<Impl2> for Impl2`. Since `MyTrait<Impl1>` is a different trait from `MyTrait<Impl2>`, there is no common trait for `Impl1` and `Impl2` that you could use to box them and put them in a common vector.

You need a *concrete*, that is non-generic, trait for dynamic polymorphism.