# Collect vector of borrowed values into vec of borrowed trait

Tags: rust, polymorphism, idioms

Is it possible to collect a `Vec<&dyn Trait>` from an iterator of values implementing `Trait`?

Here is an example, based on the [Vector of objects belonging to a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818082/vector-of-objects-belonging-to-a-trait) question:

```rs
trait Animal {
    fn make_sound(&self) -> String;
}

struct Dog;
impl Animal for Dog {
    fn make_sound(&self) -> String {
        "woof".to_string()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dogs = [Dog, Dog];
    let v: Vec<&dyn Animal> = dogs.iter().collect();

    for animal in v.iter() {
        println!("{}", animal.make_sound());
    }
}
```

this fails with `error[E0277]: a value of type "Vec<&dyn Animal>" cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type` &Dog`

however, if you use push the dogs individually into the vec (like in the answer to the original question) it works without issues.

```rs
let dog1: Dog = Dog;
let dog2: Dog = Dog;

let v: Vec<&dyn Animal> = Vec::new();
v.push(&dog1);
v.push(&dog2);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to collect an Iterator of a struct into a Vector of a trait that gets implemented by the Struct, it is possible to use the `map` method of the iterator to cast the borrowed struct into a borrowed trait.

```rs
let dogs = [Dog, Dog];
let v: Vec<&dyn Animal> = dogs.iter().map(|a| a as &dyn Animal ).collect();
```

See [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=145435ed0629e15f8d304f400e8ee779) for more info.

Comment: And since you specify the trait in the type of `v` you can also do `.map(|a| a as _)` and let the compiler do its magic.