# How do I populate a vector of trait objects using an array?

Tags: rust

Why is the following code an error? There is a blanket implementation for `[T; N]` into `Vec<T>`, so why does `dyn Foo` not match `Fooable` in this context? Is there a workaround which does not involve cloning the `Fooable`?

```rust
trait Foo {}

struct Fooable {}

impl Foo for Fooable {}

pub fn main() {
    let bar: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = [
        Box::new(Fooable {}),
    ].into();
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>: From<[Box<Fooable>; 1]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:7
   |
10 |     ].into();
   |       ^^^^ the trait `From<[Box<Fooable>; 1]>` is not implemented for `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <Vec<T, A> as From<Box<[T], A>>>
             <Vec<T, A> as From<VecDeque<T, A>>>
             <Vec<T> as From<&[T]>>
             <Vec<T> as From<&mut [T]>>
             <Vec<T> as From<BinaryHeap<T>>>
             <Vec<T> as From<Cow<'a, [T]>>>
             <Vec<T> as From<[T; N]>>
             <Vec<u8> as From<&str>>
           and 2 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>>` for `[Box<Fooable>; 1]`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ed879c94d8756154e059d2d6faec1a7f)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818082/vector-of-objects-belonging-to-a-trait https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957103/how-do-i-create-a-heterogeneous-collection-of-objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can fix the error by manually casting the box like this:

```rs
trait Foo {}

struct Fooable {}

impl Foo for Fooable {}

pub fn main() {
    let bar: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = [
        // Turn a Box<Fooable> into a Box<dyn Foo>
        Box::new(Fooable {}) as Box<dyn Foo>,
    ].into();
}
```

Remember that by default, Rust builds replaces trait method calls directly with calls to the implementation if it exists. A object's "type" only exists at compile time, at run time there are no types. `dyn` types are different. They store some extra data that allows finding the actual variant of the method to call at runtime.

### Why is assigning to a array directly OK though?

When you define a array of integers like this:

```
// this works
let k:[i8;3] = [1,2,3]
```

There is no conversion happening here. Even though the numbers are `i32` by default the numbers in the array will be interpreted as `i8` values.

It's the same in this case:

```rs
let k:Box<dyn T> = Box::new(V{});
```

Converting from a `V{}` to a `Box<dyn T>` requires a conversion, but the compiler can avoid the conversion by interpreting the right hand side as a `Box<dyn T>` from the start.

This works for arrays too, but not if there is a level of indirection:

```
// works
let k:[Box<dyn T>;1] = [Box::new(V{})]
// does not work
let b = [Box::new(Fooable {})];
let e:[Box<dyn Foo>;1] = b;
```

This is also the reason this is valid:

```rs
let bar: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = [
    Box::new(Fooable {}) as Box<dyn Foo>,
    Box::new(Fooable {}),
    Box::new(Fooable {}),
].into()
```

Even though we only have the `as Box<dyn Foo>` on the first element this changes how the entire array is interpreted.

Comment: > Thus the conversion is not not free and requires a explicit step.

Is there a reason that this does happen implicitly when not dealing with the vector? For example `bar: Box<dyn Foo> = Box::new(Fooable {});` is valid code.

Comment: @frankplow A very good question that I don't know the answer to

Comment: @frankplow @mousetail It's presumably because of the indirection through the `From` trait which can't do the cast implicitly. That's why `let baz: Box<dyn Foo> = Box::new(Fooable {}).into();` also doesn't work, but `let bar: [Box<dyn Foo>; 1] = [Box::new(Fooable {})];` does.

Comment: @mousetail I think you misread: `let bar: [Box<dyn Foo>; 1] = [Box::new(Fooable {})];` **does** work! Although only in a `let` statement, not in an assignment expression. You do need an explicit cast there. It's just that `From<T: Trait> for dyn Trait` isn't implemented, which makes sense.

Answer (score 11):

You're right. There's a blanket implementation for `From<[T; n]>` on `Vec<T>`. That means you can convert `[T; n]` into `Vec<T>` with `From::from` or `Into::into`.

More specifically, that means you can convert a `[Box<Fooable>; 1]` into a `Vec<Box<Fooable>>`, or a `[Box<dyn Foo>; 1]` into a `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`. However, you have a `[Box<Fooable>; 1]` and want a `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`, and since the `T` is different, the blanket `impl` doesn't apply.

Use an explicit cast to get the behavior you want. You just have to convince Rust that the type of the array is `[Box<dyn Foo>; 1]`, not `[Box<Fooable>; 1]` as it originally infers.

```
let bar: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = [
    Box::new(Fooable {}) as Box<dyn Foo>,
].into();
```