# Vector of tuples with different size

Tags: rust, glium

I am currenly implementing marching cubes algorithm using Rust and I faced a problem. This algorithm requires using triangulation table which I copied from GitHub. But which data structure in Rust allow us to store such a data?

Those tuples mean which edges of cubes have to be connected, so they all are different size.

```rust
pub fn tri_table()-> Vec<???>
{
   return vec![
      (),
      (0, 8, 3),
      (0, 1, 9),
      (1, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1),
      (1, 2, 10),
      (0, 8, 3, 1, 2, 10),
      (9, 2, 10, 0, 2, 9),
      (2, 8, 3, 2, 10, 8, 10, 9, 8),
      (3, 11, 2),
      (0, 11, 2, 8, 11, 0),
      (1, 9, 0, 2, 3, 11),
      (1, 11, 2, 1, 9, 11, 9, 8, 11),
      (3, 10, 1, 11, 10, 3),
      (0, 10, 1, 0, 8, 10, 8, 11, 10),
      (3, 9, 0, 3, 11, 9, 11, 10, 9),
      (9, 8, 10, 10, 8, 11),
      (4, 7, 8),
      ...
   ];
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your triangulation table is known at compile time. In that case, use static slices. That's the solution with the lowest cost, it has almost zero overhead. For the price that you can't modify it anymore afterwards.

Like this:

```rust
pub fn tri_table() -> &'static [&'static [i32]] {
    &[
        &[],
        &[0, 8, 3],
        &[0, 1, 9],
        &[1, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1],
        &[1, 2, 10],
        &[0, 8, 3, 1, 2, 10],
        &[9, 2, 10, 0, 2, 9],
        &[2, 8, 3, 2, 10, 8, 10, 9, 8],
        &[3, 11, 2],
        // ...
    ]
}
```

By doing this the data will be baked directly into the data segment of your executable, and calling `tri_table()` only returns a pointer to it, no allocation will happen and no heap memory will be used. Calling `tri_table()` multiple times will always return a reference to the same address, so also no overhead if you call it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Finomnis has already suggested an efficient solution to *your* problem. But for those who find this question from a search for a way to put different tuples in a vector, the number and type of tuples in that vector might not be known at compile time. That's usually the case with vectors.

So if you really need a **vector**, the two main approaches in Rust is to use [a vector of trait objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74974361/15602349) or a vector of [enums with values](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html#enum-values). Both approaches have their pros and cons. Enums will probably use more memory (depends on the size of the enum variant with the largest value), but a trait object requires an extra (fat) pointer (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74974361/15602349)).

Comment: Could you insert the relevant code that you linked to (externally?) links have the tendency to die in the future.