# Factory function of different types in rust

Tags: rust, factory

I'm trying to write a function in rust that builds different types of objects (all implementations of a same trait) but I'm running into troubles, not understanding if I'm trying to do something illegal or just not grasping correct syntax.
Here is a toy sample, not compiling (neither of the three variants of animal_factory function compiles):

```
enum Error {
    UnknownAnimal,
}

trait Animal {
    fn bark(&self);
}

struct Dog {}

impl Dog {
    fn new() -> Result<Dog, Error> {
        Ok(Dog {})
    }
}

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn bark(&self) {
        println!("Bau! Bau!");
    }
}

struct Cat {}

impl Cat {
    fn new() -> Result<Cat, Error> {
        Ok(Cat {})
    }
}

impl Animal for Cat {
    fn bark(&self) {
        println!("Meow! Meow!");
    }
}

/*
fn animal_factory(kind: &str) -> Result<impl Animal, Error> {
    match kind {
        "cat" => Cat::new(),
        "dog" => Dog::new(),
        _ => Err(Error::UnknownAnimal),
    }
}
*/

/*
fn animal_factory(kind: &str) -> Result<impl Animal, Error> {
    match kind {
        "cat" => {
            return Cat::new();
        },
        "dog" => {
            return Dog::new();
        },
        _ => {
            return Err(Error::UnknownAnimal);
        },
    }
}
*/

fn animal_factory(kind: &str) -> Result<impl Animal, Error> {
    if kind == "cat" {
        Cat::new()
    } else if kind == "dog" {
        Dog::new()
    } else {
        Err(Error::UnknownAnimal)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = animal_factory("cat").unwrap();
    let y = animal_factory("dog").unwrap();
}
```

Any insights? maybe I need to Box things up?

Comment: I recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74974361/15602349) description of trait objects. It should help you understand them on a deeper level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`impl Animal`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/impl-trait.html#abstract-return-types) won't work if you try to return different concrete types (`Cat` and `Dog` in your case), even if both implement `Animal`. From the docs:

> These types stand in for another concrete type where the caller may only use the methods declared by the specified Trait.

So trying to return either `Cat` or `Dog` is not going to work with `impl Animal` as your return type, due to a type mismatch between these two concrete types.

Luckily we can easily create one common type from both `Cat` and `Dog` instances that also implements `Animal`: [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html). Trait objects are annotated with `dyn Animal`, instead of `impl Animal`. Trait objects are dynamically sized so we need to wrap them into a `Box` or other kind of (smart) pointer or reference:

```
fn animal_factory(kind: &str) -> Result<Box<dyn Animal>, Error> {
    if kind == "cat" {
        Ok(Box::new(Cat::new()?))
    } else if kind == "dog" {
        Ok(Box::new(Dog::new()?))
    } else {
        Err(Error::UnknownAnimal)
    }
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9e467dc2a5679f559bf1d6a7c7a0d49b)