# Convert Box<T> in generics to Box<dyn Trait> in rust

Tags: rust, traits

How to convert Box in generics to Box.
from `Container<Box<Dog>>` to `Container<Box<dyn Animal>>`

```rust
//example
fn main() {
  let container: Container<Box<Dog>> = Container(Box::new(Dog()));

  let test: Container<Box<dyn Animal>> = container;
  // expected struct `RcHash<Box<dyn Enity>>`
  // found struct `RcHash<Box<Role>>`

  let test = container as Container<Box<dyn Animal>>;
  // non-primitive cast: `Container<Box<Dog>>` as `Container<Box<dyn Animal>>`
  // an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
}

//struct
struct Container<T> (T);
struct Dog ();

//trait
trait Animal { fn echo(&self); }
impl Animal for Dog { fn echo(&self) { println!("dog"); } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do a simple *cast* between `Box<Dog>` and `Box<dyn Animal>`, as they are not quite the same thing. Both `Box`es might act as pointers to a `Dog` instance, but `Box<dyn Animal>` will actually have a different *size*, because trait objects also have an extra pointer (for the [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)). I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74974361/15602349) to better understand that part about trait objects.

The above means you can't avoid creating a new `Box<dyn Animal>` instance, hence you can't avoid creating a new `Container<Box<dyn Animal>>` instance (because if `A != B` => `Container<A> != Container<B>` /here you could interpret `!=` as 'not compatible' or 'of a different *size*'/).

Here is an example how you can "manually" create a new `Box<dyn Animal>` instance out of a `Box<Dog>` instance:

```
let dog_box: Box<Dog> = Box::new(Dog());
let animal: Box<dyn Animal> = Box::new(*dog_box);
```

That will essentially *move* the doggie instance (not create another clone).

And this is the more complete example for your case:

```
let container: Container<Box<Dog>> = Container(Box::new(Dog()));
let cont_animal: Container<Box<dyn Animal>> = Container(Box::new(*container.0));
```

Comment: If you can deconstruct the inner value from the `Container`, you don't need a new `Box`, you can just cast it.